# how to Throw a customize http error in Scala Lagom

Tags: scala, http-error, lagom

I know how to throw a bad request in Lagom by using

`throw BadRequest("Bad Request")`

but this will return with an http error code of 400.
how do I return with a http error code of 409 (Conflict) for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your custom exception that must be inherited from TransportException:

```
val ConflictErrorCode: TransportErrorCode = TransportErrorCode(409, -1003, "Conflict")

final class Conflict(message: String)
    extends TransportException(ConflictErrorCode, new ExceptionMessage(ConflictErrorCode.description, message))
```

Then in your code, you need to write:

```
throw new Conflict("Some conflict message")
```

Comment: if I used this code, it shows that it needs to be a throwable rather than TransportErrorCode

Comment: seems like the wrong message was because the first val was also using the name of Conflict. so when I throw new Conflict, there was an error. but now its referencing to the correct Conflict